# pandas style changes ceil value unexpectedly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm using `style` in pandas to display a `dataframe` consisting of a timestamp on `jupyter notebook`.


 The displayed value, `1623838447949609984` turned out to be different from the input, `1623838447949609899`.


 pandas version, `1.4.2`.


 Can someone please explain the reason of the following code and output?
Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([[1623838447949609899]]).style
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pandas Styler, within its render script, contains the line `return f"{x:,.0f}"` when x is an integer.

In python if you execute

```
>>> "{:.0f}".format(1623838447949609899)
'1623838447949609984'
```

you obtain the result you cite. I suspect this is due to data storage of integers. Although why it pandas might be converting from a 64 bit int to a 32 bit int is unclear, and not related to Styler